# It is possible to modify already existing report within Splunk dashboard?

Tags: dashboard, splunk

I have already created report in Splunk: "splunk_report".
I want to use it in Splunk dashboard.

I have already add new panel -> new from report, but now it shows me a table (as it was defined in saved report)
I would like to get the total number of rows in this table. It is possible to make count of current report?
eg. "splunk_report" | stats count(system)

I do not want to copy whole search query, because when search in report change in the future, I have to change it in 2 places.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you add the report as an inline search (or the report generates a lookup via [`outputlookup`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/outputlookup)), what you're describing isn't possible.

If you add it as an inline search, you're back to your initial problem of needing to update it each inline search use *as well as* the original report

I often make use of scheduled reports to create lookup tables, though (for performance reasons). If you do *that*, then you can just reference the lookup table on your dashboard, and do with it whatever you want like any other lookup table:

```
| inputlookup mylookup.csv
| stats count
```

Or

```
| inputlookup mylookup.csv
| stats count by system
```

Etc

If you want to add summary data to the stats table on the dashboard, format the visualization and add totals:

[image: sample screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution: create saved search and refer to existing report:

```
<search id="save_search" ref="splunk_report">
```

And in second saved search add base search:

```
<search id="save_search2" base="save_search">
    <query>| stats count(system)</query>
```